# QML ScrollView inside Item won't scroll

Tags: qt, scroll, qml, scrollview

I want to have a **fixed header** for a *ScrollView*, so I thought that doing this would work:

```
Item {

   Rectangle {
    ---i want to be a fixed header
   }

   ScrollView {
    ---list items
   }

}
```

Basically inside the *Item* I want a *Rectangle* or *Row* to act as header and below that a *ScrollView*.

However, if I put the ScrollView inside an Item (or *Rectangle*, I tried already), nothing will scroll - the scrollbars do show, though.

Any idea on how to fix it? Or a different approach?

**edit:** I need the Item because I have some properties in it.

Comment: What's the point of adding a title to ScrollView? What a content it has? Maybe you want to use `TableView`, `ListView` etc. instead?

Comment: I started with just a ListView, but for some reason I couldn't scroll horizontally, only vertically. That's why I ended up using ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

As @folibis mentioned, you can consider using `TableView` or `ListView` since they have built-in support for header, scrolling, and delegates for your model data.

I created an example that demonstrates:

- ListView
- Horizontal scrolling with `orientation: ListView.Horizontal`
- Scroll bar with `ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { }`
- Header by setting `header` and `headerPositioning`
- Content provided by setting `model` and `delegate`

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ListView {
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        width: parent.width
        height: 120
        model: [ "Alligator", "Bear", "Cat", "Dog",
            "Elephant", "Flamingo", "Giraffe", "Horse",
            "Iguana", "Jellyfish", "Kangaroo", "Lion",
            "Monkey", "Narwhal", "Owl", "Panda",
            "Quail", "Raccoon", "Squirrel", "Tiger",
            "Unicorn", "Vampire Bat", "Worm", "Xenarthra",
            "Yak", "Zebra"
        ]
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {
            height: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
        header: Rectangle {
           width: 100
           height: 100
           color: "white"
           border.color: "grey"
           z: 2
           Text {
               anchors.fill: parent
               text: "Alphabet Zoo"
               horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
               verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
               wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
           }
        }
        headerPositioning: ListView.OverlayHeader
        clip: true
        delegate: Rectangle {
           width: 100
           height: 100
           color: index & 1 ? "#eee" : "#ddd"
           border.color: "grey"
           Text {
               anchors.fill: parent
               text: modelData
               horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
               verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
               wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
           }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! Specially with the "Try it Online" link. I'll give it a go once again with just the ListView and let you know. But I need the list to also be scrollable vertically, not just horizontally.

Comment: Please ensure that your existing question has all the information needed to answer the question properly. There was (1) no clear description of your requirements, (2) no data, (3) no runnable code snippet. If your follow up question is actually a new question, please open a new question.